# How to enable camera and mic access from WebView in Xamarin form Expanded Explanation

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I have followed the instructions on creating a custom renderer for WebView found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024600/how-to-enable-camera-and-mic-access-from-webview-in-xamarin-form). I have added permissions and I have created a class in the xxx.Droid project. As I am new to Xamarin, are there any other steps that I should also take? Do I have to register this class anywhere?

I have added permissions and I have created a class in the xxx.Droid project.

Comment: does it work?  are you having a specific problem?  Your question is lacking any real detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `xxx.Droid` is the namespace of his project. If you want use the code you should create a Renderer class in your project in the .Android package.

Second, I found a more particular article about [Xamarin - Requesting camera permissions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771557/xamarin-requesting-camera-permissions-in-webview) you can check this.

**UpGrade**

@Obsidian Delta had made his project to work. This is his project [XamarinWebviewMicrophone](https://github.com/ObsidianDelta/XamarinWebviewMicrophone).

Comment: I followed the link you gave me and got it to work. https://github.com/ObsidianDelta/XamarinWebviewMicrophone